# python tuple remove the first match appearance using only higher order functions

Tags: python, tuples

I want to write a `Rem(a, b)` which return a new tuple that is like `a`, with the first appearance of element `b` is removed. For example

`Rem((0, 1, 9, 1, 4), 1)` which will return `(0, 9, 1, 4)`.

I am only allowed to use higher order functions such as lambda, filter, map, and reduce.

I am thinking about to use filter but this will delete all of the match elements

```
def myRem(T, E):
    return tuple(filter(lambda  x: (x!=E), T))
```

`myRem((0, 1, 9, 1, 4), 1)` I will have `(0,9,4)`

Comment: why is `a` a tuple? surely a mutable data structure makes more sense if you want to *remove* something?

Comment: One way could be to convert to a list, use `index()` to find the first match, remove it, and convert back to a tuple. Also you may find the `enumerate()` function to be useful.

Comment: @pault Don't need to convert to a string, tuple has an `.index` method, just `idx = t.index(n); return t[:idx] + t[idx+1:]`

Comment: Even better @Chris

Comment: This question frustrates me: "I need a tuple, I can only use these functions." SO is for real-world solutions, not homework assignments. (-1).

Answer (score 6):

The following works (**Warning:** hacky code):

```
tuple(map(lambda y: y[1], filter(lambda  x: (x[0]!=T.index(E)), enumerate(T))))
```

But I would never recommend doing this unless the requirements are rigid

Comment: I suggest you move `T.index(E)` outside to prevent multiple computations.

Comment: "I am only allowed to use higher order functions such as lambda, filter, map, and reduce."-- but this uses `tuple()` ;)

Comment: @zipa I agree completely with you, it just seemed the op looked for a one-liner. @Chris_Rands, the op uses `tuple` so I thought it was allowed as well

Comment: Yes I know, and you also use `enumerate()` etc. My point is not that you are wrong, but that these arbitrary restriction questions are always unclear (normally bad IMO) and nearly impossible if interpreted literally!

Comment: @Chris_Rands maybe _nearly_ impossible, but not impossible. See my answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

Trick with *temporary* list:

```
def removeFirst(t, v):
    tmp_lst = [v]
    return tuple(filter(lambda  x: (x != v or (not tmp_lst or v != tmp_lst.pop(0))), t))

print(removeFirst((0, 1, 9, 1, 4), 1))
```

- `tmp_lst.pop(0)` - will be called only once (thus, excluding the 1st occurrence of the crucial value `v`)
- `not tmp_lst` - all remaining/potential occurrences will be included due to this condition

The output:

```
(0, 9, 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun, using itertools, you can sorta use mostly higher-order functions...

```
>>> from itertools import *
>>> data = (0, 1, 9, 1, 4)
>>> not1 = (1).__ne__
>>> tuple(chain(takewhile(not1, data), islice(dropwhile(not1, data), 1, None)))
(0, 9, 1, 4)
```

BTW, here's some timings comparing different approaches for dropping a particular index in a tuple:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("t[:i] + t[i+1:]", "t = tuple(range(100000)); i=50000", number=10000)
10.42419078599778
>>> timeit.timeit("(*t[:i], *t[i+1:])", "t = tuple(range(100000)); i=50000", number=10000)
20.06185237201862
>>> timeit.timeit("(*islice(t,None, i), *islice(t, i+1, None))", "t = tuple(range(100000)); i=50000; from itertools import islice", number=10000)
>>> timeit.timeit("tuple(chain(islice(t,None, i), islice(t, i+1, None)))", "t = tuple(range(100000)); i=50000; from itertools import islice, chain", number=10000)
19.71128663700074
>>> timeit.timeit("it = iter(t); tuple(chain(islice(it,None, i), islice(it, 1, None)))", "t = tuple(range(100000)); i=50000; from itertools import islice, chain", number=10000)
17.6895881179953
```

Looks like it is hard to beat the straightforward: `t[:i] + t[i+1:]`, which is not surprising.

Note, this one is shockingly less performant:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("tuple(j for i, j in enumerate(t) if i != idx)", "t = tuple(range(100000)); idx=50000", number=10000)
111.66658291200292
```

Which makes me thing all these solutions using `takewhile`, `filter` and `lambda` will all suffer pretty bad...

Although:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("not1 = (i).__ne__; tuple(chain(takewhile(not1, t), islice(dropwhile(not1, t), 1, None)))", "t = tuple(range(100000)); i=50000; from itertools import chain, takewhile,dropwhile, islice", number=10000)
62.22159145199112
```

Almost twice as fast as the generator expression, which goes to show, generator overhead can be quite large. However, `takewhile` and `dropwhile` are implemented in C, albeit this implementation has redundancy (take-while and dropwhile will pass the `dropwhile` areas twice).

Another interesting observation, if we simply wrap the substitute a list-comp for the generator expression, *it is significantly faster* despite the fact that the list-comprehension + tuple call iterates over the result *twice* compared to only *once* with the generator expression:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("tuple([j for i, j in enumerate(t) if i != idx])", "t = tuple(range(100000)); idx=50000", number=10000)
82.59887028901721
```

Goes to show how steep the generator-expression price can be...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that only uses `lambda`, `filter()`, `map()`, `reduce()` and `tuple()`.

```
def myRem(T, E):
    # map the tuple into a list of tuples (value, indicator)
    M = map(lambda x: [(x, 1)] if x == E else [(x,0)], T)

    # make the indicator 0 once the first instance of E is found
    # think of this as a boolean mask of items to remove
    # here the second reduce can be changed to the sum function
    R = reduce(
        lambda x, y: x + (y if reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, map(lambda z: z[1], x)) < 1 
                          else [(y[0][0], 0)]),
        M
    )

    # filter the reduced output based on the indicator
    F = filter(lambda x: x[1]==0, R)

    # map the output back to the desired format
    O = map(lambda x: x[0], F)
    return tuple(O)
```

**Explanation**

A good way to understand what's going on is to print the outputs of the intermediate steps.

**Step 1: First Map**

For each value in the tuple, we return a tuple with the value and a flag to indicate if it's the value to remove. These tuples are encapsulated in a list because it makes combining easier in the next step.

```
# original example
T = (0, 1, 9, 1, 4)
E = 1
M = map(lambda x: [(x, 1)] if x == E else [(x,0)], T)
print(M)
#[[(0, 0)], [(1, 1)], [(9, 0)], [(1, 1)], [(4, 0)]]
```

**Step 2: Reduce**

This returns a list of tuples in a similar structure to the contents of `M`, but the flag variable is set to `1` for the first instance of `E`, and `0` for all subsequent instances. This is achieved by calculating the sum of the indicator up to that point (implemented as another `reduce()`).

```
R = reduce(
    lambda x, y: x + (y if reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, map(lambda z: z[1], x)) < 1 
                      else [(y[0][0], 0)]),
    M
)
print(R)
#[(0, 0), (1, 1), (9, 0), (1, 0), (4, 0)]
```

Now the output is in the form of `(value, to_be_removed)`.

**Step 3: Filter**

Filter out the value to be removed.

```
F = filter(lambda x: x[1]==0, R)
print(F)
#[(0, 0), (9, 0), (1, 0), (4, 0)]
```

**Step 4: Second map and conversion to tuple**

Extract the value from the filtered list, and convert it to a tuple.

```
O = map(lambda x: x[0], F)
print(tuple(O))
#(0, 9, 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This violates your requirement for "only using higher order functions" - but since it's not clear *why* this is a requirement, I include the below solution.

```
def myRem(tup, n):
    idx = tup.index(n)
    return tuple(j for i, j in enumerate(tup) if i != idx)

myRem((0, 1, 9, 1, 4), 1)

# (0, 9, 1, 4)
```

Here is a `numpy` solution (still not using higher-order functions):

```
import numpy as np

def myRem(tup, n):
    tup_arr = np.array(tup)
    return tuple(np.delete(tup_arr, np.min(np.nonzero(tup_arr == n)[0])))

myRem((0, 1, 9, 1, 4), 1)

# (0, 9, 1, 4)
```